# How to attach click events inside click events

Tags: javascript

I have a click event that is attached via another click event. The problem is the event handler I'm attaching gets fired by the same click that fires the initial event.

The first one is actually a drag event, but i guess that when the dragged element is released over the element that is supposed to get a click handler it fires that new handler as well.

```
function obj() {
   ...
   this.whatDropped = function(drop) {
      if(drop.type == "textbox") {
         $(document).click(function() {
            //triggered immediately
         });
      }
   }
}
```

this.whatDropped() is triggered by another event.

Comment: Can you share some code and more details about what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you tried `e.stopPropagation()` from the second event that gets bound? As @ShimonRachlenko has said, it's kind of difficult to offer advice without seeing your code, though.

Comment: I have and object with a method that is triggered when a certain element is dragged and dropped within it. In that method I would like to attach a click event to $(document) and remove it again when it has been executed. But the $(document) event gets fired immediately after it has been attached.

Comment: Again, please share your code. It's impossible to answer with it. Also, could you set up a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you want? Just bind a different click function within click functions.

http://jsfiddle.net/bbrj8/

```
var firstClick = function() {
    $("#echo").text("first click");
    $("#clickme").bind("click", secondClick);
}
var secondClick = function() {
    $("#echo").text("second click");
    $("#clickme").bind("click", firstClick);
}
$("#clickme").bind("click", firstClick);
```

Comment: For anything more specific, you'd have to give more details on what you are trying to do... but perhaps you could bend this to fit your specific need.